# Android: i am a newbie. I declared a button in java file but i didnt see it in xml-file and on an emulator

Tags: java, android, button

I tried to run first example from "Beginning Android Games" book (by Mario Zechner, Apress.com):
I copied this code to my project (MainActivity.java file):

```
HelloWorldActivity.java

package com.helloworld;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button;
    int touchCount;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    button = new Button(this);
    button.setText( "Touch me!" );
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    setContentView(button);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    touchCount++;
    button.setText("Touched me " + touchCount + " time(s)");
}
}
```

but when I have run this simple application, I didn't see any button on the emulator (I have seen only an "Android" label. I tried "project-->clean..": no result. (and "project-->Build Automatically is swiched on). Where do I need to declare and describe this button? But I followed all steps described in the book. And at the end, I removed xml-file from layout folder at all.

Thanks.
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_****Edited: Added xml-files****_*__*_*__*_*____**

res-->layout-->activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.firstbuttontest2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.firstbuttontest2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you should add the button into your root layout. i mean your first layout of xml file

Comment: Sorry, do I need to do it every time by my hands? I thought it happens automatically.
For now and for future: how to force Eclipse to generate essential code?

Comment: @AlexPilugin Post your XML file also.

Comment: you can create the buttons in xml itself. if you do that no need to add anything in java side .

Comment: you have all the facility to create the controls and views in the xml file itself. then wi are you creating those things in java side.

Comment: thank you. OK. I understood, but I guess, i am better in java coding than in xml-"constructing" and, it's strange, it wasn't mentioned in the book, to place any declarations somewhere.
I'd like to type code in java-file and a xml-file will be generated automatically, now i understood i have to type declarations in xml-file first.

Comment: res-->layout-->activity_main.xml

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com    /apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    </RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 1):

Try this it might help you.

Add button to particular layout. Like this

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
linearLayout.addView(button);
```

Comment: For now and for future: how to force Eclipse to generate essential code?

Comment: i mean can i type code in java file first and than receive xml file? Or at any cases I have to declare widgets in xml file first?
I am asking it because in the book (http://www.apress.com/9781430230427) it (xml-file) wasn't mentioned.

Comment: @Alex Pilugin you should make widget in xml layout if its possible. but you can create widget in java code also.

Comment: @AlexPilugin look at this example..http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/

Comment: Thank you for link:
I read on there: 
"i copied and pasted this over the one that was there and then copied an pasted this one over the main java and when i install it only says hello world!" (The same situation for me)
"in the graphical layout you have to drag to make the button you can not just copy the code."

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is a addContentView method which may be more what you are looking for as opposed to setContentView.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

then

```
button = (Button) findviewbyid(R.id.Button1);
```

this may solve your problem